# Sometimes 'special value' instead of foreign key as reference needed

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Let's assume you have a member table with id, name, email and so on. The records are referenced in other tables with their id as foreign key.

Now sometimes there is a need for special values for example something like 'System' or 'Unregistered' instead of a foreign key and it's associated record. For sure due to constraint nothing else than an existing id is allowed in the foreign key field. And I don't want to add System, Unregistered or anything else to the member-table as these are no members at all.

So the question is now if you can give some tips or hints, or maybe you can point to some articles or blogs which deal with this matter as my search on the Internet wasn't very successful. What would be best practice to achieve this?

Comment: You can't keep the db integral and insert non-key values. Maybe try a sentinel record in the foreign table. If your ids can be negative, that would make it obvious it's such a value, I.e. System = -1, Unregistered = -2

Comment: I would do what @DavidK-J is suggesting. The other object is to add a nullable column everywhere that is referencing the member table that can take an enum of ('System','Unregistered'). Having system and unregistered as -1 and -2 in member table is much cleaner.

Comment: Why can't these values be foreign key relationships?  Sample data describing what you want to do would help clarify why a foreign key relationship isn't good enough.

Comment: FOREIGN KEYs cannot be used in all situations.